# Python sharing instance between two threads in two classes

Tags: python, multithreading, data-sharing

I have some code that needs to be in a separate thread and this code is a different class completely. I am using the multiprocess.Queue queue to share the data. Basically I want the parent base class (also the program driver) to make an instance of some other class and put that instance into a queue and send the queue to the new threaded class. When the threaded class runs and finally comes up with a value I want it to directly call a function from the instance inside the queue that was passed.

Instead, the thread terminates and calls the finally block that I have set up. How do I do this in python?

```
from multiprocessing import queue
import thread
class a():
    def main(self):
        self.classB = b()
        self.classC = C()
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.queue.put_nowait(self.classC)
        thread.start_new_thread(self.classB.run, (self.queue))
        #do stuff


class b():
    def run(self, q):
        #do stuff in try clause
        self.listen(q)

    def listen(self, q):
        c = q.get()
        c.someClassCMethod
```

EDIT:
Okay so I am now using Queue.Queue() instead. I couldn't find what the threading Queue that was mentioned.... I still am having trouble sending the instance of classC to classB and using it.

Comment: When using threads you should use the Queue class from threading.  Mixing the multiprocessing Queue with threads or vice versa is a bad idea (potentially worse than not using any Queue at all).

Comment: I didn't even know there was a queue class from threading

Comment: so can you give me a link to this threading queue?

Comment: It's in the standard libraries since at least 1.5 ... import Queue